# Android showing error while running

Tags: android, android-manifest

i have 2 activities AndroidSlite.java and SqLiteAdapter.java.. my manifest.xml file is given below.it shows No launcher activity found .while running

please help me with the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.cerebtec.androidsqlite"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />



                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
            <activity android:name="AndroidSQLite"></activity>


    </application>
    </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

```
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />



            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>
        </activity>


</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to enclose the intent filter around the launcher activity, in order to declare your launcher activity. E.g.

```
<activity android:name="AndroidSQLite"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

this way you are telling android that the launcher activity is `AndroidSQLite`